# puts to stdout not happening if expect loaded in 2 threads

Tags: windows, multithreading, tcl, expect, activetcl

I am using following version of Active Tcl on windows 10

```
C:\thread>tclsh
% puts $tcl_version
8.6
% package require Thread
2.6.6
% package require Expect
5.43.2
```

I am trying to use Expect in 2 threads.  But puts to stdout not happening when package require called in both threads.

```
package require Thread
#package require Expect

thread::create {
package require Expect
exp_log_user 1
puts "hello"
}

thread::create {
package require Expect
exp_log_user 1
puts "hello2"
}

after 2000
```

output:

```
C:\thread>tclsh samp2.tcl
hello

C:\thread>
```

Can someone please help guide on this.

Thanks in advance.
uv.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Expect is not thread-safe, so there's no way this is going to work, sorry.

You could consider using coroutines instead of threads to manage multiple sessions in parallel.  Expect can be integrated cleanly with coroutines, I give an example of one approach to this at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/coroutine%2Denabled+event+handling - search for `co_expect` on that page.

Comment: I can confirm that the inner C bits of expect are not thread safe; made the mistake of trying to use it with tcl threads once. Did not go well.